# VBA Runtime Error...but I can't click on debug

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, runtime-error

I get a runtime error but I cannot click on debug. What do I do to debug this error?

"run time error 91 object variable or with block not set" 
[image]

Comment: Are you doing manipulations where you are creating ActiveX objects? If so, put a breakpoint in front of this code - if you have a debug error in the middle of code like this you will not be able to enter debug mode (assuming the answer by @BenBlack is not your solution).

Answer (score 3):

The VBAProject within the worksheet is more than likely locked. You need to unlock it. Do this by:

- Opening up the Microsoft VBA Window ALT + F11
- Right-clicking your VBA project
- Selecting the VBAProject properties option
- Clicking on the Protection tab and unselecting the Lock checkbox